# Recording all Logins for each database in that database

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a requirement that will record the application name, the spid, and the user which does a connection to each one of my databases.  I currently need to record logins for 12 different databases and only the logins on that specific database should be recorded in the same database.

I've seen some triggers that will record logins like so.  What I am not sure of how to do is make this trigger for each database and only to record for that database.

```
CREATE TRIGGER [tr_CheckLogin]
ON ALL SERVER
FOR LOGON
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO SomeTable
    SELECT session_id, connect_time, net_transport, encrypt_option, auth_scheme, client_net_address
    FROM sys.dm_exec_connections c
    WHERE c.session_id = @@SPID and @@SPID > 50
END

SELECT db_name (p.dbid) AS [Database],
    c.session_id,
    s.program_name,
    s.login_name
    *
FROM sys.dm_exec_connections c
INNER JOIN sys.dm_exec_sessions s ON c.session_id = s.session_id
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text (most_recent_sql_handle) AS st
JOIN sys.sysprocesses p ON p.spid = c.session_id
ORDER BY c.session_id
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the issue. Your queries seem to work fine (except you're missing a comma in the second query after `s.login_name`. If there's only 12 databases, what's preventing you from manually creating a single table and running the trigger in all 12 of them?

Comment: @SchmitzIT there isn't an issue with the query but the premise of what's trying to be achieved. Since CDC does not provide any connection info the current thought if to record all logins spid,sysuser,db,hostname,appname with fn_dblog(null,null) and then the CurrentLSN of fn_dblog(null,null) to CDC.. This will be able to tie cdc.lsn => fn_dblog.lsn => fn_dblog.spid => login.trigger.spid.  The issue then become making sure since you're recording ALL logins to get the right spid connection info the the correct SPID

Answer (score 0):

A login trigger is a server trigger, so you don't do it per database.

You *could* check something like:

`sysprocesses.dbid IN (select database_id from sys.databases where name IN ('dbtoWatch1', 'dbToWatch2', 'dbToWatch3')`
but the whole idea is probably flawed.

Just because someone logins to database X doesn't mean they will stay in database X, nor that the queries they will perform are only to be performed in database X.
You can always login to master db and then do: `delete dbToWatch..sometable`

Probably you want to skip triggers and use audit or event traces to actually trace what kind of queries are running, but that's a different option.

Comment: This is a great suggestion for original poster (OP). OP might want to revisit requirements. If the requirement turns out to be that you have to track who ran what queries on 12 databases, you might want to audit queries. If such queries need to be checked for only a short duration, SQL Profiler is an option also.

Comment: @siggemannen @zedfoxus this comes from the need of trying to tie CDC to what application made the changes.  Since CDC does not provide any connection info the current thought if to record all logins spid,sysuser,db,hostname,appname with `fn_dblog(null,null)` and then the CurrentLSN of fn_dblog(null,null) to CDC..  This will be able to tie cdc.lsn => fn_dblog.lsn => fn_dblog.spid => login.trigger.spid.   Not even sure how feasible this is, my mind went directly to okay i'll, but i guess the flaw there is there won't be a new login when switching dbs?

Comment: I guess it's feasable, but 1) reading log is complicated and slow and i'm not sure fn_dblog is actually a production worthy function 2) log gets flushed 3) for your purposes you don't need the db name, enough just be able to connect a spid to a moment of time. Personally, the whole thing sounds complex, you probably have better luck adding a "Changed by application name" field to the tables of interest and set them with a trigger or something

Comment: @siggemannen thanks, i keep thinking about it but the application is so coupled and crosses multiple presentation layers without any real BLL that I'm trying to Frankenstein something together.